# Limit Width of Just One Sharepoint 2013 Wikipage

Tags: 2013, css, page-layout, content-editor-web-part, wiki-pages

I don't have access to my master pages but I've used the Content Editor web part to hide the sidebar on one page and I'd like to limit the page width.

Is there a code I can use in a Content Editor to limit the page width for that page alone?

-Christian

Comment: What do you mean by limit the page width for wiki page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to limit the width of contents on the wiki page, you can add below CSS in your Content Editor web part(Which is added on the same page):

```
#contentBox {
    width: 800px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

**Or**

```
.ms-wikicontent {
    width: 800px !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

You can specify the width according to your requirement instead of `800px`.

Comment: Awesome! Now it presents my next problem -- how do I center the page?

Comment: If you have hidden sideNavBox then it must be in center already?

Comment: Not after limiting the page width. Now it left aligns.

Comment: Try using updated code in answer

Comment: HUZZAH!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote(^) and accept as an answer.

Comment: Just so you know, I upvoted, but I'm a lowly <15-level user, so it won't actually apply my vote. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, welcome.